# React Semantic UI Font

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I start to use the React Semantic UI library, but it's not so easy to customize elements. 
I have a  basic HTML header   in y component that I want to set the Font to "Rubik"
So in my src/semantic-UI/site/globals/site.variables i added this line 
@headerFont 'Rubik', I am not sure if it's the good way to do that, also I would to also edit the font-size, line-height, and font-weight?

Comment: I believe they have the related customize styles documentation.

Comment: can you paste the link to the code by creating the sample in codesandbox or image that makes it clear, I am not sure if I understand